# JqueryDatePicker angular directive element not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for jquery date pickter. It works on Attribute method. But when i change to element it doesn't working. Here are my angular directive code

```
app.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //require: 'ngModel',
        template:'<input type="text" class="cal_datefield">',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My Markup has

```
<jqdatepicker></jqdatepicker>
```

Can you help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It looks something like:

```
app.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          //require: 'ngModel',
          replace: true,
          template:'<input type="text" class="cal_datefield">',
           link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
              element.datepicker({
                  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                  onSelect: function (date) {
                      scope.date = date;
                      scope.$apply();
                  }
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

You need to add one another option `replace`.